# Detect hanging program in bash

Tags: bash

I am working on an application for listening to and recording mms streams; currently I'm making a proof-of-concept for my boss in a bash-script. To record, I would like to use mimms:

```
mimms <mms://url> download_to_file
```

The output from mimms is:

```
connecting
<mms://url> <=> download_to_file
1MB / 10 MB (20 kB/s, 00:01:30 remaining)
```

The last line is a status message that is updated about once a second.

The problem occurs when dealing with unstable networks. When the network drops out, mimms will hang. No new data is added to download_to_file (file size is constant, and does not increase), but mimms does not exit, and does not even resume the download when the network connection is re-established. It just hangs, and does not output new lines of status messages either.

I would like to detect it when no new lines are output from mimms, kill mimms, and resume the download:

```
mimms -r mms://url download_to_file
```

But I don't know how to test for these conditions, and would very much appreciate advice on how to handle this.

Comment: related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115500/kill-a-process-if-it-goes-quiet-for-a-certain-amount-of-time

Answer (score 2):

You could launch mimms in the background (by adding a `&` to the command) and have your script wait in a loop, checking the size of the download file periodically.  If mimms is still running but the file size doesn't change, assume mimms is hung and kill it.

Comment: mimms also outputs the text "Download complete!" when it has downloaded the last part of the file, so I will still need to analyze the output of mimms to detect end of download. Besides; on a slow and unstable network (we're talking **very** slow) there is no guarantee that mimms is hung even if the file size doesn't increase in a while. The only reliable feedback from mimms is that it stops output of status messages

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution myself that relies on the output from mimms rather that the size of the file that mimms generates:

1. starting the program in the background, redirecting output from mimms to a logfile
2. read last line of that file with regular intervals
3. if the same line turns up twice in a row, kill mimms and restart it
4. repeat this until mimms outputs "Download complete!"

   ```
   LAST1="a"
   LAST2="b"
   MSG="Starting download of $PATH1"
   until [ "$LAST1" = "Download complete!" ]; do
       echo $MSG
       mimms -r $URL "$PATH1" >> log 2>&1 &
       PID=$!
       echo $PID

       until [ "$LAST1" = "$LAST2" ]; do
           LAST2="$LAST1"
           sleep 60
           LAST1=$(tail -1 log)
           echo "$LAST1"
       done
       kill $PID
       MSG="Download incomplete. Retry..."
   done
   ```